# Correct process for migration of a question "on hold"

Tags: discussion, migration, on-hold

There are many questions that are posted under Facebook tags which are more end user support questions which are perfect for Web Applications which deals with end user support questions. Since the question is on hold, should I

- flag asking for migration or
- edit the question then leave a comment saying that the question would be better fit elsewhere?

Comment: Shouldn't `[on hold]` be banned from titles now?

Comment: @Mysticial Was `[closed]` banned from titles before?

Comment: @EmrakultheAeonsTorn Yes, [closed] and [duplicate] were banned from titles since they could be confused with the actual close/duplicate messages.

Comment: Meta-tags such as `[closed]` or `[on hold]` or `[migrated]` should probably not be used in question titles, especially not at the end where they could be confused with the normal use of the meta-tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would leave a custom flag reason saying that the question should be migrated to the correct site. After about 300,000 of these flags, a moderator will go through the Facebook tags and migrate the appropriate ones.

Comment: **+1** for "After about 300,000 of these flags"